# Teaching computer science in developing countries - any literature?

Tags: reference-request, education

I've been teaching computer science in a developing country and I've seen how the everyday challenges are very different from what I was used to. The students are different. The teachers are different. The system is different.

So now that I'm starting to get over the culture shock, I'd like to draw more attention to the challenges (and maybe present some ideas of my own) by writing about my experiences and observations. I've been studying the literature but, so far, I haven't found one single paper about computer science education in developing countries. It's hard to believe that I might be the first one to write one so I'm asking for any pointers to any relevant literature, please.

Comment: I would imagine some literature on teaching CS still to be relevant. For instance, how students learn to "think in the right way", how students learn to program, and the like. If you don't disagree, what aspect are you focusing on more specifically? For example, what are the major differences between teaching CS in a developing country versus teaching CS in a developed country?

Comment: It's the additional challenges that make it different. The most common reason for students to fail a software project is that they were unable to explain anything about their code, not to mention editing and making changes to it, because "their friend helped" or someone else did the programming for them. They often say that they "cannot think". They prefer step-by-step learning where the teacher walks them through every bit of the code which they copy without having to think or understand what they're doing. There must be teachers who've tried to make a difference before...

Comment: Is this still a question you need answers to? 1) What *specific* issues to you face? Are the problems with them or with you (because you are a foreigner to their culture, if you are)? 2) Are the issues specific to CS? 3) SE questions work often better if they concern an isolated issue. I think you should a very specific list, prioritize and start researching/asking about them from the top. [academia.SE] may be the better site for questions that are not specific to CS.

Comment: We've actually proposed a StackExchange site to specifically help with CS education questions like this one. Come support us here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators?referrer=9Z3MnermjDx7JWcMHelYkQ2